# How to create a browser level image caching in hippo cms. Also suggest me how to do that in my local

Tags: hippocms

I want to know about how to leverage browser level caching and specially image caching in Hippo CMS. Also it would be great if somebody can suggest me how to do that in my local hippo setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set cache headers on your pages. This can be done in your component class.